# Text is not centered on mobile even if it is centered in developer tools

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been getting a little bit into the web development but it drives me crazy that I get always different results on different devices.
My problem is that the text in the button is not centered on a mobile device. I'm always using developer tools to check whether the content is responsive and it appears to be working and text is nicely centered.
However, on a real mobile device the text is more to pushed to the upper middle which looks really bad.
I've been using flexbox to solve the issue and have nicely and evenly centered text but I have no idea why it's not working on mobile

```css
.banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.banner-img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #000;
    transition: background-image .2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: background-image .2s ease;
    -moz-transition: background-image .2s ease;
    -o-transition: background-image .2s ease;

    background: url('../images/obrazy.jpg') no-repeat center center;
     background-size: cover;
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
   
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 100vw rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}



.banner-img img {
    transition: background-image .2s ease;
    -moz-transform: background-image .2s ease;
}

.banner-strip {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: row !important;
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
    .banner-strip {
        flex-direction: column !important;
    }
}

.strip {
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: #fff;
}

.strip img {
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

.strip:hover img {
    opacity: 1;
}
  .services-font {
  font-size:5.2vw;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.20);


  }
  
  @media (min-width:992px) {
  .services-font {
  font-size:3.1rem;
  }
  }
  
  @media (max-width:554px) {
  .services-font {
  font-size:2rem;
  }
  }
  
  .floating-icons {
  transform:translatey(0px);
  animation:float 5s ease-in-out infinite;
  -moz-animation: float 5s ease-in-out infinite;
  transition:transform .2s;
  -moz-transition: transform .2s;
  }
  
  .btn1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  background: none;
  border: 4px solid #d6aa55;
  font-family: charlemagne, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.brk-btn {
  position: relative;
  background: none;
  color: aqua;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 0.2em solid #d6aa55;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  
  align-items: center;
}
.brk-btn::before{
  content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10%;
    background: #000000;
    height: 0.3em;
    right: 20%;
    top: -0.21em;
    transform: skewX(-45deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
    transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
}

.brk-btn::after{
  content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10%;
    background: #000000;
    height: 0.3em;
    left: 20%;
    bottom: -0.25em;
    transform: skewX(45deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.45 cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
    transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
}

.brk-btn:hover::before{
  right: 80%;
}

.brk-btn:hover::after{
  left: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner" style="height:100vh" id="services">
        <div class="banner-img" data-img="images/obrazy.jpg">

        </div>

        <div class="banner-strip" >
            <div class="strip" data-image="images/tattoo/Background.jpg" >

                <a href="tattoo.html" class="btn1 gold mb-4 brk-btn">Tattoo
                </a>

               
                <a href="tattoo.html">
                    <img src="images/Tattoo-machine-Icon-4.png" alt="tattoo-icon" class="floating-icons"
                    style="width: 60px; height:60px">
                </a>

            </div>
            <div class="strip" data-image="images/rm80-jj-07-naturebackground_1.jpg">
                <a href="beauty.html"
                   class="btn1 gold mb-4  brk-btn">Beauty

                </a>

                <a href="beauty.html">
                    <img src="images/mascara.png" alt="mascara-icon" class="floating-icons"
                        style="width: 60px; height:60px">
                </a>

            </div>
            <div class="strip" data-image="images/Closeup_Macro_Belly_Body_piercing_Drops_517337_1280x853.jpg">
                <a href="piercing.html" class="btn1 gold mb-4  brk-btn">Piercing

                </a>
                <a href="piercing.html">
                    <img src="images/piercing_icon2_white.png" alt="piercing-cion" class="floating-icons"
                        style="width: 60px; height:60px">
                </a>


            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: how text is centered in developer tools

Comment: Possibly the mobile device in question has a browser that doesn't support flex?

Comment: Well when I'm changing devices in developer tools the text is perfectly centered on each device but on the actual site on mobile it's not.

Comment: And I'm using Chrome so I don't think that would be the case. Or?

Comment: Are you using a `!doctype`?

Comment: Yes I am using !DOCTYPE